# A conjecture concerning symmetric convex sets

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

### Question:

Let's suppose that $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex and symmetric so:

\begin{equation}
x \in S \iff -x \in S \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Now, if we define the radius of $S$ as $R$ such that:

\begin{equation}
R = \sup_{x \in S} \lVert x \rVert \tag{2}
\end{equation}

and use (2) to define:

\begin{equation}
V = \{x \in S: \lVert x \rVert = R\} \tag{3}
\end{equation}

then I conjecture that:

\begin{equation}
S = \text{conv}(V) \tag{*}
\end{equation}

I have worked out special cases of this problem within the context of high-dimensional probability but I suspect that it's generally true.

Might there be a theorem which guarantees this result?

### Special case:

1. As some people are voting to close this question I'd like to share my intuition about a special case as I think it might clarify my perspective.
2. I was thinking in particular about symmetric convex polytopes and my intuition was that all symmetric convex polytopes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose vertex set equalled $V$ in (3) were regular polytopes.

### Remark:

I consulted several texts on convexity in high dimensions and couldn't find an answer to this question. For this reason I decided to ask the question here.

Comment: It's even worse than in the answers given below: unless $S$ is assumed to be closed, $V$ can well be empty!

Comment: I implicitly assumed we want to also assume that $S$ is closed and bounded (otherwise we can get $R=\infty$ or $V=\varnothing$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the set 
$$S:= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2+4y^2 \leq 4 \}$$

This is convex and symmetric, and $R=2$.

But $V= \{ (2,0), (-2,0) \}$ and $\mbox{conv}(V)= \{ (x, 0) : -2 \leq x \leq 2 \} \neq S$.

**P.S.** About the new question.

Let $A=(0,1), C=(0,-1)$ and $B,D$ be the intersection between the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and the line $y= \alpha$ where $0<\alpha<1$. Let $B'$ be the reflection of $B$ in the $x$-axis.

Then $AB'CD$ is convex, symmetric has $V= \{ A, B', C, D \}$ but it is not regular unless $\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, I think.

Comment: Has this obstruction anything to do with the fact that the isometry group of S is of order greater than 2?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN I don't think so, you can take this example and expand the positive $x$ axix by a factor of $\alpha >1$ but keep the negative part unexpanded. Then $V$ becomes a single point, and there is no isometry.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Also see my PS about the new question.

Comment: @NickS Is $ABCD$ symmetric? $ABCD$ is symmetric about $x=0$ but not about $y=x$ and $y=-x$ as required.

Comment: @AidanRocke You are right, I need to replace $B$ by $-B$. See the edit, I think it is now.

Answer (score 5):

Take any convex, symmetric, bounded set $T$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Choose any point $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|p\|>\sup_{x\in T}\|x\|$ and let $S$ be the convex hull of $T\cup \{\pm p\}$. This set is convex and symmetric, $V=\{\pm p\}$, and the convex hull of $V$ is just the line segment connecting $p$ and $-p$. It is easy to construct counterexmples in this way, for example if the original set $T$ has non-empty interior.